# UIView holds a strong reference

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, weak-references

I have such a code

```
let view = UIView(x: x, y: y, w: sideSize, h: sideSize)
view.addTapGesture(action: { [weak self] (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> () in
    view.reversePop()
})

extension UIView {
    public func reversePop() {
        // nothing here
    }
}
```

When I use instruments I see that the ram usage increases, hence it doesn't release memory. When I comment out button.reversePop() the ram usage doesn't increase.

What can I do to prevent memory leak?

Comment: Why are you adding `UITapGestureRecognizer` on `UIButton`? `UIButton` can handle taps by itself, without recognizers. Memory usage increase is not a reliable detection of a memory leak. Probably there is no memory leak.

Comment: fixed it, now its uiview

Comment: So what do you think is the reason for the linear increase in heap?

Comment: I pinpointed the leak. The rest of the code is all commented out. When I comment out, view.reversePop() = no problem, when I leave it like this = problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this closure you capturing view every time you tap. You need to use weak reference of UIView, so your code might look like

```
let view = UIView(x: x, y: y, w: sideSize, h: sideSize)
view.addTapGesture(action: { [weak view] (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> () in
    view.reversePop()
})

extension UIView {
    public func reversePop() {
        // nothing here
    }
}
```

So, ***instead of `[weak self]`, you need to use `[weak view]`,*** because you are not calling self inside closure, no needs to weakify self.